# How to seperate a sentence like this

Tags: php

How to separate the sentence by "comma" and at last using "and " in PHP Like

"Bruce_Campbell is an actor and director and creator and producer and musician."?

now i want to to show the the sentence like this...

""Bruce_Campbell is an actor , director ,creator , producer and musician.""

Comment: did you tried anything?

Comment: explode() into an array then rebuild the string like you want

Comment: yes i tried but i cannot do this

Comment: First explode() by seperated as "and" then using for loop append everything with "comma" and find last element apend "and" before it..

Comment: You can do this or look at robbmj answer, which is simpler

Comment: result is this .. Raj_Kapoor is an actor, director, creator, editor, producer, winner. wich is not my required answar

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to replace the last and in the string.

```
$str = "Bruce_Campbell is an actor and director and creator and producer and musician.\n";
$except_last_and = substr_count($str, 'and') - 1;
$resStr = preg_replace("/and/", ' , ', $str, $except_last_and);
echo $resStr;
```

But Gautam3164 is correct you should Google first.

And the PHP manual is a great resource.

https://www.php.net/preg_replace

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

Comment: Though `Sandy_Campbell is a singer and is in the band land of hand.` is not going to work ;p

Comment: No it wont work, but I think that any arbitrary string is outside the scope of the question. If not the question should be closed as too broad.

Comment: there is a simple fix...

Comment: to put spaces around the `' and '` in count occurrences, but again it still wont work for any arbitrary string. Just the one you proposed.

Comment: result is this ..
 Raj_Kapoor is an actor, director, creator, editor, producer, winner.
wich is not my required answar

Comment: @HastaLaVictoria, my bad. `str_replace`'s 4th param is set to the number of occurrences replaced. `preg_replace` will do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

One line solution:

```
$str = "Bruce_Campbell is an actor and director and creator and producer and musician.";
print str_replace(" and ",", ", substr($str, 0, strripos($str, 'and'))).substr($str, strripos($str, 'and'), strlen($str));
```

> Bruce_Campbell is an actor, director, creator, producer and musician.

Comment: That statement is the exact opposite of optimization. In addition it is unreadable.

Comment: No, change the code not the commentary.